# Return all distinct values for one column including null, and then count based on a condition

Tags: sql, join, null, subquery

This is piece of a larger query I have.  I want to return a list of all profit centers, with the incident count for those within the date range.  I want the profit center listed, even if no incidents were reported in the date range.  This has been working fine.

However now some records have been introduced where the profit center is NULL.  I would like for those to show up in the list as 'N/A' with the incident count for the NULLs.

```
SELECT DISTINCT cast(plants.profit_ctr as varchar(50)) + ' - ' + cast(plants.profit_ctr_name as varchar(50)) AS Profit_Center, COALESCE(h.Incident_Count, 0) AS Incident_Count 
FROM JMART.[safety].vwHELPForms AS plants
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT profit_ctr, COUNT(*) AS Incident_Count
FROM JMART.[safety].vwHELPForms 
WHERE cast(rec_date as date) >= cast(@startdate as date) 
AND cast(rec_date as date) <= cast(@enddate as date) AND ratings > 0 
GROUP BY  profit_ctr) AS h
ON h.profit_ctr = plants.profit_ctr
```

How can I accomplish this?

*EDIT*

If I run

```
SELECT profit_ctr, COUNT(*) AS Incident_Count
FROM JMART.[safety].vwHELPForms 
WHERE cast(rec_date as date) >= cast(@startdate as date) 
AND cast(rec_date as date) <= cast(@enddate as date) AND ratings > 0 
GROUP BY  profit_ctr
```

I get

```
NULL    295
101100  7483
101150  116
101200  445
101400  3784
```

I've tried

```
SELECT DISTINCT cast(plants.profit_ctr as varchar(50)) + ' - ' + cast(plants.profit_ctr_name as varchar(50)) AS Profit_Center, 
COALESCE((SELECT COUNT(*) AS Incident_Count FROM JMART.[safety].vwHELPForms AS h
WHERE profit_ctr = plants.profit_ctr AND cast(rec_date as date) >= cast(@startdate as date) 
AND cast(rec_date as date) <= cast(@enddate as date) AND ratings > 0 
GROUP BY  profit_ctr), 0) AS Incident_Count
FROM JMART.[safety].vwHELPForms AS plants 
order by Profit_Center
```

which gives me (same as what I'm currently getting)

```
NULL    0
101100      7483
101150  116
101200      445
101400      3784
```

I want

```
N/A     295
101100      7483
101150  116
101200      445
101400      3784
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NULL values are going into the second table in your join, rather than the first.  So, they are lost by a `left outer join`.  Instead, you want to use a `full outer join`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       coalesce(cast(plants.profit_ctr as varchar(50)) + ' - ' + cast(plants.profit_ctr_name as varchar(50)), 'N/A') AS Profit_Center,
       COALESCE(h.Incident_Count, 0) AS Incident_Count 
FROM JMART.[safety].vwHELPForms plants full OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT profit_ctr, COUNT(*) as Incident_Count
      FROM JMART.[safety].vwHELPForms 
      WHERE cast(rec_date as date) >= cast(@startdate as date) AND
            cast(rec_date as date) <= cast(@enddate as date) AND ratings > 0 
      GROUP BY  profit_ctr
     ) h
     ON h.profit_ctr = plants.profit_ctr
```

Assuming that `profit_ctr` is not repeated in the `plants` table, you can dispense with the `distinct`.  It adds unnecessary processing and may not be needed.

Comment: We're getting closer! Changed to a full outer join and now I get 2 NULL records returned.  One with the proper incident count and one with 0

Comment: @RememberME . . . Did you add the `coalesce()` to the `select` clause?  As for the second NULL, it may be caused by a NULL value in the first table.  If so, you might want to remove it by adding `where plants.profit_ctr is not NULL or Incident_Count is not NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `LEFT JOIN`, null profit centers will show up in result as `NULL`. And since you are using `DISTINCT` they will be collapsed to one row. And for the `Incident_Count`  column you can use `coalesce(cast(h.Incident_Count as varchar(50)), 'N/A')`

PS. I assumed you are using MS SQL Server 2012.

Comment: The NULL profit centers are not showing in my result.  I also want "N/A" as the profit center name and the count for null profit centers as the incident count.

Comment: If you want to join on `NULL`s, you have to change your join condition like `coalesce(h.profit_ctr, 'NULL') = coalesce(plants.profit_ctr, 'NULL')`. And about NULL profit centers not showing up, there must be something else going on in some other parts of your query. Check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/04972/2